# .net: Best practice for exception handling while using Transactions?

Tags: .net, sql-server, exception, transactions

Is there any best practice for exception handling while using transaction? I should say that I use Sql server as my data source and VB.net 2010.

Thank you

Comment: yes, depending on the exception, the usual action would be a rollback....

Comment: The question is very vague... Are you after something specific?

Comment: Begin the transaction in a try block, roll back in the catch block, and re-throw the exception.

Answer (score 2):

An IDbTransaction will be automatically rolled back when it's disposed.  So the normal pattern looks something like the following (C#, I'll leave the translation to VB.NET as an exercise):

```
using(SqlConnection connection = ...)
{
    connection.Open();
    using(SqlTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction(...)
    {
        ... do database stuff

        // Last line in the using block commits the transaction
        transaction.Commit();
    } // Transaction disposed here - if Commit wasn't called, it will be rolled back
} // Connection disposed here
```

I.e. you don't need to explicitly call Rollback in case of an exception.  You will rarely call Rollback explicitly - it would only be necessary if you detect a condition mid- transaction (e.g. business rule violation) that requires an explicit rollback.

Exception handling will normally be done at a higher level, i.e. there may be a try/catch block in the calling code.

Answer (score 1):

As "using" is not available in VB you have to program something like that below (sorry is in C# ... i cannot write vb by heart). This is the functional equivalent than the using statement.

```
connection.Open();
SqlTransaction transaction;
try {
    transaction = connection.BeginTransaction(...)

    ... do database stuff

    // Last line in the using block commits the transaction
    transaction.Commit();
} finally {
    if (transaction != null) transaction.Dispose();
}
```

Further it is always recommended not to use the native APIs but the TransactionScope classes. It is important as maybe you want to add other transactional resources.

Comment: Thanks for the addition. Unknown for me so far. Was added with VS2005. My knowledge was obviously from before.

Answer (score 0):

oh and regarding the exception handling. Well it is often a theoretical question. Most people catch and swallow the exception and show error messages. Others, more theoretical people just cleanup (using using or finally blocks) and let the exception hit the runtime (system message) or catch them in a generic exception handler at the runtime.